# Missing variables when refreshing a page, angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an edit page with some floor information data (floor name and floor number). When I hard refresh the page I loose the floor information data. It looks like this: [image] . I am not able to keep the values after a hard refresh. Any tips?

I have a function that is on click that looks like this, with routing to a appconfig.js file:

```
goEdit(floor: Floor) {
    this.$state.go('xxx.xxx.xxx.edit', {
      locationId: this.location.id,
      floorId: floor.id,
      floor: floor,
      backUrl: 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
    });
  }
```

The routing code looks like this:

```
.state('xxx.xxx.xxx.edit', {
          url: '/xxx/xxx/:locationId/edit/:floorId',
          template:
            '<edit [location-id]="$resolve.locationId"' +
            ' [floor-id]="$resolve.floorId"' +
            ' [floor]="$resolve.floor"' +
            ' [back-url]="$resolve.backUrl"></edit>',
          parent: 'main',
          params: {
            locationId: '',
            floorId: '',
            floor: {},
            backUrl: '',
          },
          resolve: {
            locationId: /* @ngInject */ function($stateParams) {
              return $stateParams.locationId;
            },
            floorId: /* @ngInject */ function($stateParams) {
              return $stateParams.floorId; 
            },
            floor: /* @ngInject */ function($stateParams) {
              return $stateParams.floor; /
            },
            backUrl: /* @ngInject */ function($stateParams) {
              return $stateParams.backUrl;
            },
          },
        })
```

The edit component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss'],
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() backUrl: string;
  @Input() locationId: string;
  @Input() floorId: string;
  @Input() floor: Floor;
  public floorName: string | undefined;
  public floorNumber: number;
  public floorToEdit: Floor | undefined;

  constructor(
    @Inject('$state') private $state: any,
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.floorName = this.floor.name;
    this.floorNumber = this.floor.floorNumber;
```

I get the locationId and the floorId after hard refresh, but not the floor object.
Therefor I have tried to use a getFunction I have access to that returns the location object from the locationId and that object has a floor list where I can find the floor object (this was not successful either). Here is that code:

```
 this.xxx.getLocation(this.locationId).subscribe(
      results => {
        this.location = results;
        this.floorToEdit = results.floors!.find(floor => floor.id === this.floorId);
        );
      },
```

Comment: You can store in Session Storage. When page loads initially store it in session storage and when you do hard refresh get value from session storage and assign values accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store in Session Storage. When page loads initially store it in session storage and when you do hard refresh get value from session storage and assign values accordingly.