# Show splash screen only once on app load using angular pwa

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen

I have created a sample splash screen component in my Angular PWA application. I want to show the splash screen only once when the application starts. Right now it is displaying on every refresh on any page inside the app including the starting of my app.

How can I stop load splash screen on every refresh ?

**App component:-**

```
<app-splash-screen></app-splash-screen>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Splash screen component:-**

```
windowWidth : string | any | number;
  showSplash: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.windowWidth = +'-' * window.innerWidth + 'px';

      setTimeout(()=> {
        this.showSplash = !this.showSplash
      },500);

    },2000);
  }
```

**Splash screen HTML :-**

```
<div class="app-splash-screen" *ngIf="showSplash" [ngStyle]="{left: windowWidth}">
    <div class="app-splash-screen-inner">
        <div class="app-logo"><mat-icon>eco</mat-icon></div>
        <div class="app=label">Welcome</div>
        <div class="app-loader"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can store in Session Storage. When page loads initially store it in session storage and when you do hard refresh get value from session storage and assign values accordingly.You can refer my answer here -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648003/6777125

Comment: @KrunalShah I am storing as suggested by Apporva ( below answer) but I am not getting how can I use that storage on other component for refresh ?

Answer (score 2):

This component control the show/hide splash screen, the steps will occur like this:

1- the browser will download index.html file in your server, and after will search from files indicate by index.html like: "runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js, vendor.js" with duration of 300 milliseconds (in my case);

2- After that files download the page will show the splash screen;

3- After all "angular resolver"  will make the requests to your server to get your data components;

4- After all images, medias, fonts will be download

5- After, when all download and load, the splash screen will be hide

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'sei',
   templateUrl: './sei.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sei.component.css']
  })   
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   public showSplash: boolean = true; //Show or hide splash screen

   window.onload = (event) => {
     this.showSplash = false; //Trigger when everything load
   }
 }
```

But we have a problem here, because the "splash screen" only is visible when the angular files is downloaded (index.html, "runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js, vendor.js") we need wait all this angular files to show the splash screen during app load all components, images, resolver, etc.

We want start "splash screen" when the browser get the first index.html file, at this moment we want start show the splash screen and skill the other angular files.

go to your index.html and below "app" tag you can create your  "splash screen", this will show at the moment your browser get angular main index.html file.

```
 ...
 <body>
   <app></app> //YOUR APP
   <div id="splashScreen">
     splash screen, loading angular, wait... 
   </div>
 </body>
 <style>
  .splashScreenFadeHide{
     opacity: 0; //turn transparent
     transition: opacity 1s linear; //after 1 second
   }
 </style>
 ...
```

and to hide the splash screen when every thing was load, you will make:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit(): void {
     window.onload = (event) => { //triger when every thing is load (files, assets, components' resolver, etc)
     
    // All good so add clas "splashScreenFade" to hide the splash screen slowly 
    document.getElementById("splashScreen").classList.add("splashScreenFadeHide")
   }

    //we are listening the "splasn screen" turn transparent and after apply the "display = none"  
   document.getElementById("splashScreen").addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => {
     document.getElementById("splashScreen").style.display = 'none'
   })
  }
}
```

Now we have a splash screen since the first file is load by browser, and hide only when all files, images, resolver, etc is read.

Give me a like if this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using an option from `window` object like this:

```
window.PerformanceNavigationTiming.redirectCount= 0 // not refresh 
window. PerformanceNavigationTiming.redirectCount = 1 // page refresh 

.
.
.
IsRefresh = !!window.performance.navigation.type;
```

Based on the above condition you can show and hide the splash in the splash component.

Another way of doing this can be by session or local storage, you can create a key  like `appInit` if it exist don't show the splash else show it.

As per request, How can you use `session storage`. It works per browser tab when user opens a new tab it creates new session and session storage. check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for more details.

When you first time load the app, you can create a session key name `isShowSplash`. You can do it in splash constructor.

```
windowWidth : string | any | number;
  showSplash: boolean = true;

  constructor() { 
       // it will be null if it doesn't exist
       const isShowSplash = sessionStorage.getItem('isShowSplash');
       if (isShowSplash) {
           // don't show splash 
           this.showSplash = false;
       } else {
           // show splash 
           this.showSplash = true;
       }
       sessionStorage.setItem('isShowSplash', JSON.stringify(false));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.windowWidth = +'-' * window.innerWidth + 'px';

      setTimeout(()=> {
        this.showSplash = !this.showSplash
      },500);

    },2000);
  }
```

Comment: I guess in `window.performance.navigation` , navigation has been depricated. Also do I need to use in timeout only ?

Comment: No, you don't need to use the timeout. And if navigation is deprecated, you can use local storage or session storage. I have added the updated one for you.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Also I am not aware how to store the splash screen on local/session storage. Can you provide an example for this ?

Comment: I have added that in the answer, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I guess boolean should be stringlify `sessionStorage.setItem('isShowSplash', JSON.stringify(false))` . I tried this value is getting stored as well but the splash screen is still appearing after refresh. Value is not getting true . How other component will know this ?

Comment: Add that in the splash and if the app is already init then you don't need to show the splash based on the key exist or not.

Comment: Add that in the splash means ?

Comment: You need to show and hide splash component based in app already initialised or not. When you create a key in session telling app is already initialsed you can hide and show splash component based on tha exist exist or not? Am I amking any sense?

Comment: You mean if `isShowSplash = false` in storage after initialize , I will use this local storage boolean in app.html `<app-splash-screen *ngIf=""></app-splash-screen>` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the contents of session storage too. It just matter how you toggle your splash screen ngIf